# Swift. GeneratorOf<T> generate function doesn't return proper generator

Tags: ios, swift, generator, sequence

I use playground to play a little with sequences and generators. 
So I created function that returns GeneratorOf struct that suppose to implement GeneratorType and SequenceType. I expect that generate will give me new full generator that I can traverse through again. But it didn't for my countDownGen2.

I suppose that I misunderstood something.

What is wrong here? and how to use GeneratorOf properly?

```
func countDown(start: Int) -> GeneratorOf<Int>
{
    var i = start
    return GeneratorOf {return i < 0 ? nil : i-- }
}

var countDownGen = countDown(10)

for i in countDownGen
{
    println(i)
}

var countDownGen2 = countDownGen.generate()

for i in countDownGen2
{
    println(i)
}
```

Comment: See http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/GeneratorType/: Requires: next() has not been applied to a copy of self since the copy was made, ...

Comment: If I move calling generate method just after creating countDownGen it changes nothing.

Comment: No, the next() is called in the first for loop: try commenting that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeneratorOf<T>.generate()` [returns a copy of itself](http://swiftdoc.org/type/GeneratorOf/), and in your code, every *copy* of it shares the same reference to one `i`

So, when you do `countDownGen2 = countDownGen.generate()` after `countDownGen` is exhausted, `countDownGen2` is also already exhausted.

What you should do is something like:

```
func countDown(start: Int) -> SequenceOf<Int> {
    return SequenceOf { () -> GeneratorOf<Int> in
        var i = start
        return GeneratorOf { return i < 0 ? nil : i-- }
    }
}

let countDownSeq = countDown(10)

for i in countDownSeq {
    println(i)
}

for i in countDownSeq {
    println(i)
}

let countDownSeq2 = countDownSeq

for i in countDownSeq2 {
    println(i)
}
```